# Laravel Repository Pattern Contract

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel, laravel-4, repository-pattern

I am trying to implement the repository pattern using Laravel. I can understand the advantages of having interfaces to abstract the data storage.

But what about the objects returned by the methods defined in the interface. Should they also be defined in some kind of abstract class?

For instance:

```
class UserRepository implements UserInterface {
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(Model $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function find($userId)
    {
        return $this->user->find($userId);
    }
}
```

by doing this in my controller:

```
$user = UserRepository::find(1);
$user->name
```

am I breaking the design pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: according to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) you always have to depend on abstractions not concretions. If one day you need to change the implementation of that Model, you'll have to change that repository class, also going against the [Open-Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

So then in order to get my business logic independent from the Eloquent model it seems that I would have to abstract the user in an "AbstractedUser" class that would implement the repository interface. The same would go for all other business entities.

Then I could extend these abstracted classes and pass them the Eloquent Models.

Am I over designing this?